# Use Hard Drive as Ram for Hyper-V

Tags: virtualization, memory, hyper-v

Is it possible to use hard drive space as virtual RAM for Hyper-v? I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 Enterprise as the host and we are running Ubuntu 13.10 as the client OS.

Comment: That's what the Windows page file _is_, in essence.

Comment: I seriously hate all moderators on this site. I can't ask a simple question without getting banned. Wow.

Answer (score 3):

You're essentially asking if you can create a VM that appears to have more memory than is present in the physical server.  The answer is no.  If, however, with recent versions of Hyper-V, you try to start a VM that could run in a host but for which there is not enough available RAM, Hyper-V will start the VM without all the guest RAM committed, backing the guest RAM with a swap file.  This shuts off as soon as the Dynamic Memory agent within the guest can reclaim enough RAM from the guest to make the swap file unnecessary.

The truth is that all OSes supported within Hyper-V have the ability to page data in and out.  And those OSes will do that more efficiently with the knowledge they have of themselves than Hyper-V could do externally.  So it makes more sense to let them do the paging rather than do it externally.